# Android event tracking in Analytics Audiences

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I have kind of a tricky question without an answer (I went through the documentation but did not find what I was looking for) :

I am tracking two specific events in my app, one is the `start` of a GPS tracking, the other one is the `stop` event. In Firebase Analytics, I am able to select those events in order to create an audience.

The audience I want is when an user triggers the `start` event of the GPS tracking process, but does not go through the whole process and does not trigger the `stop`event.

So basically when I create the audience I have to select both `start`and `stop` event, but the thing is I actually have no value assigned to those events. For the moment, as a test case I told the audience to track if `start > 0` and `stop <= 0`.

I suppose it is not going to work as expected. How should I track the event in the Android app, and how should I retrieve it in the audience creation ? By default, is my `start` event value is the number of times the event triggered ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not mention which SDK you are using (Android, iOS, etc. please make your question more precise) - I will assume it's Android.

When logging an event, you can set parameters. A parameter is made of a key and a value. If you want a value assigned to your event, you must use a predefined key : [FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Param.html#VALUE). In this case, the value is accumulated automatically for each event type.

The following snippet will do the work for your start event, stop will work the same way of course :

```
private void logStartEvent() {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE, 1);
    firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("start", bundle);
}
```

Then you should be able to create an audience with start > 0 and stop <= 0

Hope this helps.